# How to block HTTP analyzer to decode ma HTTPS data?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, https

I am using u web service developed in wcf. And it has made secured using digital certificate.

The data decrypted at client side itself.

I found that it does "man-in-the-middle" approach to do the same.

But I could not get a explanation about how to block HTTPS analyser to decrypt the data.

Can anyone help me with some code or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack, you need to ensure that the SSL certificate is trustworthy. If the https traffic can be intercepted then either the SSL certificate isn't from a trusted source, or the analyser has access to the private key.

If you want to learn more and see how it works, have a look at this post about Fiddler. Fiddler acts as web proxy and can be configured to decrypt https using man-in-the-middle.

[Why make use of HTTPS when Fiddler can decrypt it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245718/why-make-use-of-https-when-fiddler-can-decrypt-it)