# Can you intercept what url is being called with an https request?

Tags: url, fiddler, wireshark

Assuming I'm writing a desktop application with .NET that utilizes an API key, if I make an https request with my API key in the url can an application like wireshark or fiddler intercept that traffic and in turn discover my API key?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245718/why-make-use-of-https-when-fiddler-can-decrypt-it for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Fiddler instead of Wireshark as it's higher-level and the UI is better suited for working with HTTP. It also includes a built-in SSL proxy which allows for MITM attacks against processes running on your own system which would enable you to look at and modify HTTPS requests.

Comment: So it is possible to grab the full url from https requests using fiddler?

Comment: @Rawr Yes. You can get the domain name from the `Host:` header (or the certificate Common Name) and the resource path from each HTTP request.